# Locate --regex with negative lookahead

Tags: regular-expression, locate

#### Problem

I tried to implement a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) when searching a file with `locate` like this:

```
locate --regex "apple(?!t)"
```

However I'm getting the following error, because there seems to be some substitution going on:

> locate: invalid regexp `apple(?touch latex_preamble.tex)': Invalid preceding regular expression

How can I make this work? I tried `apple(?!t)` and `apple(?!t)` as well.

**NOTE:** I'm aware I can do this with:

```
locate apple | grep -v applet
```

but I would like to know how I can get the regular expression to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several implementations of `locate`, and the ones I'm aware of want either POSIX extended regexps, or POSIX basic regexps.  Neither support lookaheads.

Comment: Thank you! In that case I'll have to resort to `grep`.